# Fire off events from SQL Server to Azure Event Hub

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventhub

I have an on-premises SQL Server 2008R2. I need to send the rows as an event to possibly Azure Event Hub from multiple tables whenever there is a new row or modification to existing row.

This is to facilitate real-time ingestion from sql server to azure vent hub whenever any changes happen.

Please note following points:

1. None of the tables have a reliable timestamp or IDENTITY column
2. No CDC or change tracking enabled
3. Cannot modify the schema or create new database objects (like trigger, stored procedure etc..)

Anyway to achieve this using Azure Functions/Logic Apps or other any other service - with above points to consider. Any ideas, thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "playback the entire history"? The function/logic app to be able to resend the events from SQL to EventHub?

Comment: I think "playback the entire history" is bit of a distraction to the main question. I am going to remove that. I basically want changes (new/modification rows) to particular tables in sql server db to be fired as events to Event Hub.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Database Audits?

You have mentioned Azure Event Hub, but not where the data would go to after hitting the Event Hub. The Event Hub is not a data store but places the events onto a queue for later processing - so what is your final processing as that may also hint at other possible solutions?

Comment: can you please elaborate on "Have you looked at Database Audits"? The data get picked up by Stream Analytics and then to downstream systems and Power BI

Comment: Hi Martin, if you need to ask a question, just add a comment rather than posting an answer ;-) Cheers

Comment: @Thomas at the time I was still very new and didn't have reputation points to add a comment.  All good now though :-)

Comment: @MartinCairney, sure no worries , I understand :-) Just people may down vote your answer. So I suggest you to delete it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just a concept, because the solution is relatively big:

As far as you are not allowed to change anything on the Database schema/configuration, then a possible approach could be to use a Scheduled Function/Logic app, to periodically query your SQL Server and then output to the Event Hub. For this kind of operation I would personally prefer Functions, because I would have more detailed control on the processing. One way or another both services should work.

The interval on which you would query the SQL Server depends entirely on how quickly does your source data change.

Because you don't have any idea on when the source data has been changed/added/deleted, you have to make a kind of replica: be it full or partial. In any case you should have some unique identifier of your events. Each time you query the source data, you have to compare the results with the previous ones and then decide what is added, deleted, changed. This will be very slow if the source data is big. However, I can't figure out another approach. There could be some improvements, however, if you query the source data quite often searching for:

- what has been changed, from those events that are already read (identified by their unique identifier)
- what has been deleted, from those events that are already read (identified by their unique identifier)
- what has been added - not present in those events that are already read (identified by their unique identifier)

So, for each query you should pass the identifiers of all read events.

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: "...get only the data since the last execution" - that's the sticking point. If you look at my points in my question - I have no way to determine rows that have changed/new since last execution.

Comment: sorry, changed my answer. I don't see many options for you. With my team we have had similar issue, and we made something like this

Comment: Appreciate, I know I don't have lots of options. Your idea is not bad, thanks for that. Its just defeats the real-time ingestion. I have got 50GB data and its resource intensive to identify the changes.